# Distance search script optimization

Tags: r, geo, purrr

I am writing a script to determine the number of locations of various types (15 different values) that fall within 5 to 30 miles in increments of 5 miles of a zip code centroid.   (ex. # of locations of type 1 within 5 miles of zip, # of locations of type 1 within 10 miles, etc).

My inputs to the script are a data frame with zips and the centroid, a vector of distances, and a list of 15 dataframes with lat/longs where each df is a location of a certain type.

In total, I have 14000 locations to check against 30000 zip codes.  In the result set, I want a dataframe where each row is the zip and the columns list the number of locations of 1 of the 15 types that fall within the specified distance.  So there are 90 columns for each zip (15 types * 6 distance thresholds)

I have the script, but it is extremely slow.  It takes 85 seconds to get the results for 2 zip codes, and over an hour for 100.  I am running Microsoft Open R, and have 12 cores on my machine.

I use the purrr package for my loops.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(geosphere)

distance = seq(5, 30, 5)
names(distance) <- seq(5, 30, 5)

res.by.zip <- by_row(zip.smp, function(x) {
  zip.long <- x[["longitude"]]
  zip.lat <- x[["latitude"]]

  dist.vars.lst <- map(distance, function(dist) {
        # Calculate df with distance to zip centroid for each location
        dist.lst <- map(locations.lst,
                    function(uniq.cat.recs){
                      distm(as.matrix(uniq.cat.recs[,c("longitude","latitude")]), 
                            c(zip.long, zip.lat), fun = distHaversine) %>% as.data.frame()
                    } # close pmap function
         ) # close map

    # Calculate number of locations that fall within distance threshold
    recs.lst <- map_int(dist.lst, function(u) {
      filter(u, (V1*0.0006213712) < dist) %>% nrow()  # Haversine output in meters, change to miles
    }
    ) # close map - int vector of # of store types for each distance
  } # close function
  ) # close map - list of integer vectors - each outer element is the distance we test for 
  res.vec <- simplify(dist.vars.lst)
  y <<- names(res.vec)   # save as global var because can't figure out how to get R to automatically append the proper var names to the df
  return(res.vec)
} # close map function
,.collate = "cols"
) # close by_row

names(res.by.zip)[4:ncol(res.by.zip)] <- y   # append column names to the df
```

Here are links to the df's with the zips and the locations:
[zips](http://www.filedropper.com/zipsmp)

[locations](http://www.filedropper.com/locationslst)

How can I make this more efficient?  If it is not possible to do locally, what options do I have to use R in the cloud for more robust processing power?

Also, I'm not really sure that MRO is taking advantage of all the available cores.  If I run `getMKLthreads()`, output is 12.

If I run `setMKLthreads(20)`, it tells me number of threads is already at maximum.

UPDATE:

I tested this with a regular Euclidian distance function instead of the Haversine and it ran ~60times faster (about 1 minute for 100 zips).  This suggests tha it's the distance function that's responsible for the long computation time.

Comment: You could try to use another approach while using spatial tools. For instance, use `rgeos::gBuffer` with a fixed distance around your zip codes to build a multiple spatialpolygons. And then use `sp::over` to cross all your locations and get the list of polygons they fall in.

Comment: @StatnMap, so I'd have to create 6 spatial polygons for each zip code (to account for the distance thresholds).  Then, for each zip, I'd count the number of locations of each of the 15 types falling within these zip thresholds .  This sounds like an extra step and would be justified only if sp:over is blazing fast.  Do you have any experience with how fast sp::over runs?

Comment: You won't need to separate the 15 types, except that this can allow you to run your code in parallel. I can't tell you how fast this method will be. This is only the way I would do it while working with spatial data an using spatial tools. (Sorry but for the moment, I do not really have time to write you a code proposition...)